# JavaFX - Fast changing data, GUI update too slow

Tags: java, javafx

I have a program that does some kind of calculation on an external computer. That program sends information about its progress which is then shown in a GUI. It roughly works like this:

```
public void receiveData(final int step, final double errorRate)
{
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            stepLabel.setText(""+step);
            errorLabel.setText(""+errorRate);
        }
    }
}
```

By the system output on the external computer, I can see that the program performs its calculation very fast. The GUI on the other hand shows program not fast enough. When the calculation is done, I can still see the values changing because the queue at Platform.runLater() still contains runnables with updates.

How can I fasten the changes?

What also would be a good soluation is that if the GUI does not show every single change in values if its not fast enough. I.e., if there is a Runnable in queue at Platform.runLater() for step 200, but receiveData() receives a value for 201, the value for 200 doesn't need to be shown because it already is obsolete.

Comment: Maybe remove all the Runnables in the queue when you receive new data?

Comment: Maybe using a bound _property_ for the texts, bypassing the runLater's.

Comment: Removing the runnables is not possible, since I don't have access to that list. Also, other threads could also perform changes on the GUI which I don't want to remove.

Comment: I don't think bounding is possible. I get the data from an external program via JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply throttling technique - put your messages into a queue and each 300ms choose the latest or aggregated/average value. This would avoid too many scheduled runnables and updates for the UI.

This method is present in RX* frameworks, i.e. in [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS), but seems not yet being available in RxJava.